# How can I run a single script for just one matrix in a multi-matrix travis build

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, travis-ci

My travis file looks something like this:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.2
sudo: false
env:
  matrix:
    - DESTINATION="OS=9.2,name=iPhone 6s" SDK=iphonesimulator9.2
    - DESTINATION="OS=9.1,name=iPad Pro" SDK=iphonesimulator9.2
    - DESTINATION="OS=9.0,name=iPhone 6s Plus" SDK=iphonesimulator9.2
script:
  - xcodebuild -project MyProj.xcodeproj -scheme UnitTests -sdk "$SDK" -destination "$DESTINATION" -configuration Debug ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO test
  - xcodebuild -project MyProj.xcodeproj -scheme FunctionalTests -sdk "$SDK" -destination "$DESTINATION" -configuration Debug ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO test
```

I have two kind of tests: UnitTests and FunctionalTests. I would like to run UnitTests just for the `- DESTINATION="OS=9.2,name=iPhone 6s" SDK=iphonesimulator9.2` matrix but it ends up running for all 3 matrices. How can I specify UnitTests to run for a single matrix and have the other two matrices run the FunctionalTests ?

Comment: `if [ "$DESTINATION == "OS=9.2,name=iPhone 6s" ] && [ "$SDK" == "iphonesimulator9.2 " ]; then COMMAND; fi`

Comment: yup that's what i was thinking of doing as well if I didn't get a better answer. Guess I'll just try that for now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually answered by набиячлэвэлиь:

```
if [ "$DESTINATION == "OS=9.2,name=iPhone 6s" ] && [ "$SDK" == "iphonesimulator9.2 " ]; then COMMAND; fi
```